# Can vinyl siding be painted or stained?

Tags: painting, vinyl-siding

Can vinyl siding be painted or stained, and more importantly, does it last or will I be repainting every year like a wood sided house?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can paint it.  Make sure you clean it very well (use a [TSP Cleaner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001GOGQW)) and then use a primer first (although some sites say you can get away without a primer).

Also make sure to paint it a lighter color than the current one:

> I assume you're painting with a
>   lighter color paint - vinyl siding
>   painted a dark color can have problems
>   with warping and expansion in direct
>   sun.

from http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Alt/alt.home.repair/2008-08/msg03475.html

The expected life of the paint job will be dependent on the weather conditions for that area of the house and probably be about the same as a wood sided area.